# Is it possible to force dark mode splash screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-darkmode

I am implementing dark mode and I have a dark mode version of splash screen in `drawable-night`. Then in app's `onCreate` I call:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
}
```

However, it seems that the splash screen still follows the system settings and not the one I set. I tried doing the same in app's `init` but that yielded the same result. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible as of now.

Big applications like WhatsApp or Slack behave the same way and also don't have a dark splash screen unless the system-wide dark mode setting is **on**.

Answer (score 1):

On API 31 and above you can now use getSplashScreen().setSplashScreenTheme(int themeId). There is still no support for lower versions.

Comment: does it work? it's not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate() {

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)

super.onCreate()
}
```

Try this

Comment: Does not help. I think that if this worked, my try with `init` would also work.